# Draw sample from "binned" distribution in R

Tags: r, random, sample

Suppose I have a vector of counts binned into classes i=1...k, i.e.

```
v = c(n_1, n_2, ... n_k)
```

for a total N = Sum n_i. I want to sample n < N without replacement. The naive approach to this is to use v to create a vector vnew with n1 1's, n2 2's, ... nk k's, and then apply

```
s1 = sample(vnew, n)
t1 = table(s1)
```

and then re-bin.

Surely there is a simpler way to do this in R. It's basically down-sampling, but with respect to a single distribution and a specified sample size (rather than two distributions).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `rep` to create `v` and then `sample` by drawing `n` of it, e.g.,

```
> v <- c(2, 7, 4, 5, 3)

> n <- 15

> table(sample(rep(seq_along(v), v), n))

1 2 4 5
2 6 4 3
```

Comment: That's the approach that I took. I was asking if there's some simple function in R or one of its packages that would do this in one line.

Comment: `sample.int(length(v), n, replace=TRUE, prob=v)` maybe.

Comment: @jay.sf yes, I think yours seems closer to what OP is after. maybe you can post it as an answer :)

Comment: The sample.int line of code doesn't return what I'm looking for, e.g. if v = c(1,5,10,4), and n = 4, it returns e.g. (1,3,3,4), which doesn't sum to n=4.